# Declare SQL Cursor passing in a variable name

Tags: t-sql, cursor

I would like to decare a Tsql cursor, but pass it a string variable instead of a SELECT statement.  Is it possible and how would you do it?  What I have below is not working. Looking for something like:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT sysobjects.name 
            FROM [#database#].[dbo].sysobjects' 
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '#database#', @MyDBName) 
DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FOR @sql
```

Comment: There's an undocumented stored proc called sp_msforeachdb, you might find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the whole cursor dynamic and you have to use `sp_executesql` , this should work:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000) -- needs to be nvarchar!
SET @sql = 'DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT sysobjects.name 
            FROM [#database#].[dbo].sysobjects' 
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '#database#', @MyDBName) 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
OPEN c
....
```

But please read this here first when you want to use dynamic SQL in SQL Server: [Obligatory dynamic SQL info link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Is c going to be in scope, after the exec?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thanks for the hint, local cursors won't work, see: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#cursor0 I changed the code.